# Can I add a hotkey to my secondary mousewheel on my MX Master 3 mouse?

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys, logitech, mxmaster3

Im using a Logi MX master 3 mouse from Logitech. This mouse has two mousewheels and i would like to add the second mousewheel to a hotkey in VS code!

When trying to apply the mousewheel to a hotkey in VS code It does not notice the mousewheel. (Nothing happens)

Is it possible to add hotkeys to mousewheels?
I have the MX Master drivers installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Logitech Options](https://www.logitech.com/en-gb/product/options) software to bind your scroll wheel to a key combination, then [bind the same key combination](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) in VS Code to whatever you want.